# Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. Rails Capistrano

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app running Ruby ruby 1.9.3p194 and Capistrano 2.12.0.

I've been able to deploy to our production server in the past, but I'm now trying to deploy to a different server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit) for testing.  So I changed my deploy.rb with all of the proper information (server ip, app name, repo, etc).

When I do a cap deploy I get the following:

```
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:app/exigead.git master"
    command finished in 920ms
  * executing "git clone -q git@github.com:app/exigead.git /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103 && cd /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103 && git checkout -q -b deploy e6efe3c07a4148d840af414ae0fe113adc05a0fa && (echo e6efe3c07a4148d840af414ae0fe113adc05a0fa > /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103/REVISION)"
    servers: ["72.14.181.99"]
Password: 
    [72.14.181.99] executing command
 ** [72.14.181.99 :: out] Enter passphrase for key '/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa':
Password: 
 ** [72.14.181.99 :: out]
    command finished in 15062ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103/public/assets &&\\\n        mkdir -p /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103/public &&\\\n        mkdir -p /home/deploy/exigencad/shared/assets &&\\\n        ln -s /home/deploy/exigencad/shared/assets /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103/public/assets"
    servers: ["72.14.181.99"]
    [72.14.181.99] executing command
    command finished in 66ms
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103/Gemfile --path /home/deploy/exigencad/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["72.14.181.99"]
    [72.14.181.99] executing command
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] 
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] from extconf.rb:36:in `<main>'
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] 
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] 
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] Gem files will remain installed in /home/deploy/exigencad/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] Results logged to /home/deploy/exigencad/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] continue.
 ** [out :: 72.14.181.99] Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
    command finished in 5788ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103; true"
    servers: ["72.14.181.99"]
    [72.14.181.99] executing command
    command finished in 76ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20140809150103/Gemfile --path /home/deploy/exigencad/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 72.14.181.99
```

It looks like bcrypt-ruby is failing to install.  But also bundler is failing to run even though it's installed on the server (had to do this manually before deploying)

Anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing the following.

Installing ruby1.9.1-dev and manually installing the bundler gem.

All gems build properly on my server now.